# IE8 support of (html5) ajax navigation

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

Is it true that to enjoy Ajax navigation 
IE8 support only **window.location.hash** mechanism but not **window.history** ??

Those 2 API are described officially [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#history)
but it isn't said which of them is supported in IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [this table](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#html5-web-applications), History Management is not supported by IE 8, but the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) is.